# Using SVG's getCTM with getElementById

Tags: javascript, svg

I have dynamically generated SVG, and I need to find the current coordinates of one of the elements. According to the SVG documentation, this can be done with the getCMT() function. I have not been able to get this to work in JavaScript. Here is an example code fragment:

```
thing = document.getElementById("#bx" + myState.myId);
matrix = thing.getCTM();
```

I correctly select the SVG element, which is a 'g' element, so it has a transform matrix. When I try to get the matrix, it returns a 'null'. This is a simple task, so it is very puzzling that it does not work. I've spent some time looking for examples, but they all seem to use static SVG directly loaded in HTML. What am I missing?

I've also tried this with getBBox() and had the same result. I'm using the current FireFox release.

---

I found out what the problem was. I was using getElementById in conjunction with the *visibility* attribute. I was setting visibility to *hidden* in the root of the SVG structure, and then setting the visibility attribute to *visible* in a nested g element. The getElementById function returns null when intermediate nodes are not displayed. Calling getElementbyId before changing the visibility made things work.

Here is a reference to where I found this out: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=756985

The specifics have to do with whether the SVG is attached or not. If it is not attached then everything must be visible. If it is attached then it is possible to use hidden/visible.

Thanks to those who responded. In FireFox, it didn't make any difference if there was a "#" at the start of the getElementId argument, but it's good to know the correct syntax. Thanks.

Comment: You're sure thing != null? If so probably best if you post a complete testcase rather than just a couple of lines.

Comment: Typically you should leave off the leading `#` in that `getElementById` call.

Comment: Thank you for this, helped me track the object being null in Firefox.